# changing test cases from junit to mockito in android app

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

i am trying to test out an email field in login screen. i want to change the following code using mockito. can it be done. pls help??

```
class EmailValidatorTest {

    @Test
    fun emailValidator_CorrectEmailSimple_ReturnsGood() {
        val email = "name@email.com"
        assertThat(EmailPasswordChecker.getEmailState(email)).isEqualTo(EmailState.GOOD)
    }

    @Test
    fun emailValidator_CorrectEmailSubDomain_ReturnsGood() {
        val email = "name@email.co.uk"
        assertThat(EmailPasswordChecker.getEmailState(email)).isEqualTo(EmailState.GOOD)
    }

    @Test
    fun emailValidator_InvalidEmailNoTld_ReturnsIncorrect() {
        val email = "name@email"
        assertThat(EmailPasswordChecker.getEmailState(email)).isEqualTo(EmailState.INCORRECT)
    }

    @Test
    fun emailValidator_InvalidEmailDoubleDot_ReturnsIncorrect() {
        val email = "name@email..com"
        assertThat(EmailPasswordChecker.getEmailState(email)).isEqualTo(EmailState.INCORRECT)
    }

    @Test
    fun emailValidator_InvalidEmailNoUsername_ReturnsIncorrect() {
        val email = "@email.com"
        assertThat(EmailPasswordChecker.getEmailState(email)).isEqualTo(EmailState.INCORRECT)
    }

    @Test
    fun emailValidator_EmptyString_ReturnsEmpty() {
        val email = ""
        assertThat(EmailPasswordChecker.getEmailState(email)).isEqualTo(EmailState.EMPTY)
}
```

here is some more helper code->

```
object EmailPasswordChecker{
//some code that i cant share

        }

enum class EmailState {
    GOOD,
    INCORRECT,
    EMPTY
}
```

these are simple tests that i wrote using JUnit. but now i need to change them using mockito. can someone help me with the code? i am fairly new to testing so i am not exactly able to figure out how this framework is working.

Comment: Mockito is a tool for testing: you can mock objects that are dependencies to the currently tested object. It is not a testing framework - you still need JUnit for it. But, if your code does not call any other object, you don't need that.

Comment: The current JUnit test could be refactored as `@ParameterizedTest` - you are testing the same method, but with different parameters

Comment: @gaborsch so this code cannot be converted so that it uses mockito? i need another object and then i call EmailPasswordChecker using that object?

Comment: What other objects `EmailPasswordChecker` uses?

Comment: i was saying i can mock another class which uses `EmailPasswordChecker`. will that work?

Comment: btw i tried `@ParameterizedTest` it says `this annotation is not available to target 'member function'`

Comment: Yes, it can work, but you can mock instance methods only, not static methods.

Comment: ok i will do that. thanks for your help.